# jQuery Divs aren't performing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html

The jQuery code isn't showing up correctly with the functions. Nothing is happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/student/common/scripts/jquery.min.js">
</script>       
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document.ready(function(){
        $("#Div1").click(function(){$("#Div1").css("font-size","40px")});
        $("#Div2").click(function(){$(this)
            .css({"background":"crimson","color":"blue"})
        $("#Div3").click(function(){$("div").css("background":"beige");});
        $("#Div4").click(function(){${(this_.hide();});
        $("#Div5").mouseover(function(){$(#Div4").show();});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(document.ready(function(){` just should be `$(function() {`

Comment: dont you see any syntax errors in the console? Hint `$(document.` should be `$(document).`

Comment: ^^ This, plus closing parenthesis are missing on the `#Div2` line.

Comment: You forgot to close one of those (third one)!

Comment: $(document.ready(function(){ => $(document).ready(function(){ ... you missed a parentheses

Comment: This question **is** off-topic because it is about a bunch of typos

Comment: Debug your code yourself :) https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 1):

### **tl;dr**, change it to:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Div1").click(function() {
        $("#Div1").css("font-size", "40px");
    });
    $("#Div2").click(function() {
        $(this).css({ "background": "crimson", "color": "blue" });
    });
    $("#Div3").click(function() {
        $("div").css("background", "beige");
    });
    $("#Div4").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("#Div5").mouseover(function() {
        $("#Div4").show();
    });
});
```

---

Typo city! Here's what you need to fix it:

1) This line:

```
$("#Div3").click(function(){$("div").css("background":"beige");});
```

Should be (colon switched to comma):

```
$("#Div3").click(function(){$("div").css("background","beige");});
```

2) This line:

```
$("#Div4").click(function(){${(this_.hide();});
```

Should be:

```
$("#Div4").click(function(){$(this).hide();});
```

3) This line:

```
$("#Div5").mouseover(function(){$(#Div4").show();});
```

Should be (missing `"`):

```
$("#Div5").mouseover(function(){$("#Div4").show();});
```

4) You've nested your click events by missing a `});`, place that at the end of the `$("#Div2")` click event to add the missing `});`